# ${_csrf.parameterName} and ${_csrf.token} return null

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security

For me the CSRF token is not generated.... I searched many links still did not find a solution

Getting this error

> Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf'
>   or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="postUrl"/>
    <form action="${postUrl}" method="post" >
        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">     
        <p>Invalid username and password.</p>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">  
        <p>You have been logged out.</p>
        </c:if>
        <p>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
             <input type="text"
                id="username" name="username" /> 
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password"
                id="password" name="password" /> 
        </p>


        <input type="text" 
        name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />

        <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you [configured it](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure)?

Comment: if you use a spring-form `<form:form>` it will add the csrf token for you (assuming you have it set up correctly)

Comment: Same problem here. It is a csrf token, where should he give as path, since you suggest <form:form> tag.@NeilMcGuigan

Answer (score -1):

For me I got the same error, and the problem was I was missing the below configuration in web.xml,

```
<!-- Spring Security Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: @Downvoter I don't know the valid reason why would anyone downvote a solution which worked for me which can be useful to many others even though this might not be the exact solution to the question asked by OP. It's fine but state the reason why you downvoted lol.

Comment: Because it doesnt work just with that. Have to add <http> config and other things in security config xml. I agree though should add comment. I had a note to come back to this. I'd post the xml but I don't have it handy now.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, just enable the CSRF tag in the web.xml  and it worked as it worked for me.