# ${_csrf.token} on jsp always null with spring-security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, csrf, auth0

I am working on a legacy Spring MVC application and I need to pass the _csrf token to a javascript but, after introducing spring-security (in particular auth0 user authentication), these two rows are always null:

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

This is how I override the configure(HttpSecurity http):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@PropertySources(@PropertySource("classpath:auth0.properties"))
@Order(-2 /* SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER */)
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests() 
            .antMatchers("/download/**", "/resources/**", "/plugins/**", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/colors/**", "/callback", "/login", "/loggedout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
    }

}
```

I have removed the ***DelegationgFilterProxy*** from the web.xml because it should be created extending the ***WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*** and in according with this SO question [${_csrf.parameterName} and ${_csrf.token} return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983403/csrf-parametername-and-csrf-token-return-null) I should re-add but, if I do, I get a startup error (missing springSecurityFilterChain).

So, the question is, why my token are null if I have implemented WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and I do not disable the csrf?

Comment: have you tried adding .add().csrf() in configuration. May be in legacy spring csrf is disabled by default.

Comment: Yeah... done... but without success. I am using new version of spring (5.0.x)

Comment: How do you render the html ? It should be worked when it's jsp